Could an aircraft possibly achieve a vertical nose dive at 90 degrees without breaking up?
I've been wondering, is it possible for an aircraft to remain intact even if it is in a vertical nose dive? Is this physically, structurally and aerodynamically possible?
In March 21, 2022, China Eastern Airlines Flight 5735 crashed at high speed into the ground, killing all 132 passengers and crew on board. The investigation isn't complete yet, but a security camera on the ground captured a video moments before the crash and revealed a shocking phenomenon: the plane was almost on a vertical nose dive at extremely high speed. However, I've been wondering, is this really possible? Maybe the angle the camera was positioned with respect to the aircraft somehow made the aircraft look like it was on a vertical nose-dive? Because, wouldn't the aircraft be torn apart if it were in such an attitude? Data suggests that the aircraft was descending at speeds of 640 km/h (~0.5 Mach) at first and then reached  or even exceeded 1126 km/h (~0.94 Mach) in the final moments before impact (link). According to my research and knowledge, any aircraft would break apart mid-air if

An explosion that damages the fuselage, no matter how small. This can be inside of the aircraft (for example, a bomb or a fuel explosion), or outside of the aircraft (for example, missiles, think MH 17).
Rapid depressurization at a high altitude, which almost always causes structural failure.
An aircraft not designed to fly at sonic or supersonic speeds (like the supersonic jetliner Concorde, with a maximum speed of Mach 2.04) but somehow is flying at that speed.
Extremely violent movement and turns or severe wind and turbulence combined with a weird attitude (or AOA) and high speed.

Flight 5735 seems to meet the last two conditions. So, my question is, is it really possible that Flight 5735 was in a vertical nose dive towards the ground at nearly Mach 1 and didn't experience an in-flight breakup? Or, was it just not possible, or that the plane did break up in-flight (unlikely, however, because the video shows the aircraft intact). Most importantly, is it generally possible for an aircraft to dive nose-down vertically at high speed (which will always happen because of the attitude and AOA) and not explode/break up in-flight? Glad if anyone can give me some insights into this question. Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm not looking for speculation or explanation/investigation on how/why China Eastern Airlines Flight 5735 crashed. I'll leave that for the officials. I just used it as an recent and extreme example here. Rather, I'm looking for a general answer for the structure and performance of aircraft with bases in physics and aerodynamics.

The essence of your question seems to be, can an airliner (or an aircraft in general) undergo a sustained vertical dive without breaking up, i.e. without experiencing substantial structural failure.  I would suggest modifying the question to feature the "without breaking up" part more prominently in the title, and in the opening few sentences.

@quietflyer Thanks a lot for the advice, I've edited my post to reflect the change. Can you please check it out? Do you think my edited question convey my intention more clearly?

Any reasons, downvoter? Please leave a comment telling me how I can improve. Also, if you had downvoted me because of the reason @quietflyer pointed out, I've already edited my post to express my intentions more clearly, so please check it out. If you think my edit improves the post and the new edited post is good enough, then please upvote me back so others browsing the Questions list will view my question and possibly answer. Thanks in advance for the attention.

Normal transport aircraft (FAR Part 25 certification) have structural design cruise speed called VC.
These aircraft must demonstrate that they can achieve a maximum dive speed VD.  This speed must satisfy:
VC < 0.8 VD
If the speeds are limited by Mach number (instead of equivalent airspeed), you can use the same ratio for Mach number.  There are other ways to demonstrate compliance, but this ratio is the simple one.
The published maximum operating speed VMO/MMO for the 737NG is 340 KCAS / 0.82.
VMO can be chosen up to VC.  So, if VMO = VC, then VD must be 425 / M 1.025.
In flight test, the aircraft will be placed into a dive until it reaches VD and is then safely recovered.  Typically, the active limit in a dive is flutter.
In cases where the aircraft is too draggy to reach VD/MD (even in a powered dive), then the more complex rules come in for establishing what VD / MD must be.
For example, the aircraft starts at VC, is placed into a 7.5 degree dive for 20 seconds, and then recovered at 1.5g.  The maximum speed achieved in this 20 second dive can be use as VDF.  This test would be repeated at multiple altitudes etc.
VDF is the flight test demonstrated dive speed -- this is the highest speed achieved in the flight test of an aircraft.
So, back to your question....
When you place an aircraft into a dive, it will accelerate.  A subsonic aircraft will experience a rapid rise in drag as it approaches Mach 1.  This means that these aircraft will reach a terminal velocity in a dive (even power on) that is not terribly higher than their cruise speed.
Transport aircraft must demonstrate that they are structurally sound in a dive.  This includes avoidance of flutter in the dive.
It is possible that a transport aircraft could be placed into a dive and would reach terminal velocity before it would reach structural failure.

Thanks for the answer. So you mean that aircraft actually can not exceed its operational speed too much, and thus won't break up.

Re "Transport aircraft must demonstrate that they are structurally sound in a dive. This includes avoidance of flutter in the dive."  -- surely not a vertical dive, which was the subject of the question.  Re "It is possible that a transport aircraft could be placed into a dive and would reach terminal velocity before it would reach structural failure."  --  I find this hard to believe.  But, then, you learn something new every day--

@AircraftEnthusiast007 Correct.  The transonic drag rise of these aircraft is quite dramatic.  Before Yeager and the X1, some doubted if it was possible to break the "Sound Barrier".

@quietflyer The orientation of the dive does not matter in the flight test for demonstrating VD.  It does of course matter for establishing the terminal velocity.  Look at transonic drag rise, it presents a near vertical wall.  The increase of drag with speed in this region is tremendous.

@RobMcDonald Thanks for the explanation! I do have a question though: does the attitude of the aircraft really don't matter? I figured that if for example, the wind is blowing horizontally, is it true that the stress on the structure of the aircraft is equal for one that is traveling straight and one is descending straight down in a vertical nose-dive?

@AircraftEnthusiast007 My point was that the regulations don't say anything about the aircraft's attitude when demonstrating VD.  You set VC, compute VD, then conduct flight tests to demonstrate VDF.  The attitude does not matter.  When conducting structural analysis, engineers typically consider the speed and the load factor (g's), but don't worry about the attitude.  Aircraft are naturally very strong in the nose-to-tail direction.

I assume your question is to exclude fighter jets and unlimited category aircraft which by design certainly can do pretty much everything, the physiology of the pilot being the limiting factor.
First of all as to your research on the reasons that would lead into in flight break up:
There is at least one incident where an airliner has sustained a hit from a missile, but was able to land, the Korean Airline flight 902.
Rapid depressurization as such does not necessarily cause in flight break ups. There are several cases of rapid, even "explosive" depressurization with limited or even no damage to the airframe.
There are documentes cases in which an airliner has lost parts of its fuselage and still managed to remain controllable.

United Airlines flight 811 lost a cargo door and surrounding structure at high altitude, yet it landed safely.
Aloha Airlines flight 243 lost a substantial part of its fuselage during flight, but incredibly enough the crew managed remain in control and land the plane

As for the question itself whether or not it is possible for an aircraft to dive vertically and not break up I would say yes, it is, at least for a short period of time. An example of this would be the China Airlines flight 006. Due to engine failure and improper control inputs the aircraft tumbled into a dive losing 30000 feet of altitude in 2.5 minutes. The flight data recorder only worked periodically during the dive, and there is no certainty that an actual fully vertical dive was present at any time, but when it comes to stressing the airframe this case is extreme: loadings exceeded 5 g's and there was severe vibrations due to high speeds.
